# CSS3 @font-face. Get width of imported font

Tags: javascript, css, font-face

This is how i import the TTF font:

```
@font-face {
    font-family: bt;
    src: url('Monospace 821 BT.ttf');
}
body {
    font: normal 21px bt;
}
```

And this is how i calculate the Width of font characters:

```
window.onload = function() {
    var k = document.createElement('div');
    k.innerHTML = 'M';
    k.style.position = 'absolute';
    document.body.appendChild(k);

    var size = [
        k.offsetWidth,
        k.offsetHeight
    ];

    document.body.removeChild(k);
    alert(size[0]+' '+size[1]);
};
```

Using this method i am able to calculate the width & height successfully of the system's fixed-width fonts like "Monospace", "Monaco" etc.

But as for the imported font the results I get vary every time i change the character 'M' to something else. Also, YES, i am able to write on-screen with the imported font, so indeed it is successfully loaded in the `<body>`.

How can this behavior get fixed?

Comment: Is the imported font a for sure a fixed–width font?

Comment: Since this is the behavior I'd expect from a non–fixed–width font, I'd probably open the font in a different application and check if it might just be the font’s problem.

Comment: As i mention in the question, i am able to write with this font in a HTML textedit control, so it's not the font's problem.

Comment: That's not what I mean. A typeface contains more information than just the shapes of the letters. There's information about kerning and kerning pairs, etc.. And not every font is of equal quality. Just because it claims to be a monospaced font, not every letter has to be necessarily the same width.

Comment: Do you get the same behavior with "Courier"?

Comment: I don't see a question. What, exactly, are you asking?

Answer (score 0):

Browsers handle things like kerning differently, so the spacing between letters (even if it's a monospace font) isn't guaranteed to be uniform. Particularly so if the font has varied metrics; the appearance of the characters might be the same, but the actual metrics assigned to each glyph could be wider or thinner. What you see isn't always what you get as far as digital typography is concerned.

If the application you're using requires setting some arbitrary dimensions based on the font size, I'd suggest using a relative CSS unit instead like `ch`, which pertains to the width of the character "0" as rendered in the element's current typeface.